# How to get number back to 1 when going on a new page

Tags: php

I have a problem with my application. First of all on a previous page the teacher types in the number of sessions (exams) he or she wants to create and types in the number of questions they want per session.

Now on the current page, If I have multiple sessions or exams in other words, then lets say I am on the first exam, it will let me add question numbers for the first exam. Now If I  submit the form then it will take me to the second session and I have to add new question numbers in from scratch. Now if I try to add a question number a question number, then it does not add a question number into the table.

I have figured out where the problem occurs. The problem occurs in the code below:

```
if (qnum > <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) {
    return;
}
```

What I have stated above is that if the number of questions added, is more than the number of questions stated on the previous page, then do not add question number. So lets say I have 2 sessions and I want only 1 question per session. In the first session it adds question number 1, but when I get to second session, it doesn't add question number 1 for second session because it thinks it is question number 2, even though it is suppose to be question 1 for second session.

So how do I get it so that if user goes to second session, it knows that the question number starts back at 1?

Below is full code on how question number is added into a table:

```
  var qnum = 1;
    var count = 1;

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

        if (qnum > <?php echo (int)@$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) {
        return;
    }


        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");

        $tr.append($qid);
        $tbody.append($tr); 

        count++;


        $(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum);

        ++qnum;
        $("#questionNum").text(qnum);  


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use $_SESSION instead of $_POST. Anyway, using @ is a bad habit.

Comment: The "@" sign makes the parser to ignore an error. In your code it says literally "do not throw error when $_POST[] is not set"

Comment: $_SERVER gathers within itself both $_GET and $_POST. On some machines $_POST does not work as it should, depends on machine's settings.

Comment: Hi, Fixed it if I change $_POST to $_SESSION, then it works, thank you. If you change $_SERVER to $_SESSION in your answer then I will mark it best answer because I wouldn't of known to change the $_POST :)

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked, but it has nothing to do with session ) Check whether  there's session initiation on your page, that includes the number you seek. Then $_SESSION is the answer.